# How to get yesterday's date with Momentjs?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

So, my question is simple, how do I get yesterday's date with MomentJs ?
In Javascript it is very simple, i.e.

```
today = new Date();
yesterday = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1))

console.log(yesterday)
```

But how do I achieve this with MomentJs ?

Comment: moment().add('days', -1);

Comment: There is also `new Date(Date.now() - 8.64e7)`. ;-)

Answer (score 282, accepted):

Just like this: `moment().subtract(1, 'days')`. It will give you the previous day with the same exact current time that is on your local pc.

Comment: Tried this at face value but didn't work for me. I had to provide some type of format to the result. E.g. 'moment().subtract(1, 'days').calendar()' or 'moment().subtract(1, 'days').toDate()' or 'moment().subtract(1, 'days').format("MM/DD/YYYY")'

Answer (score 108):

Also :

```
moment().subtract(1, 'day')
```

It will give you the previous day with the same exact current time that is on your local pc.

Comment: I'm using this method since a month in a snippet, and I just found out that this is not work properly at the beginning of the month. So `moment(date).subtract(-1, 'day')` on the first day gives back the last day of the current month instead of the last day of previous month. Does anybody know more about?

Comment: can you try with `moment().subtract(1, 'day')` instead of `moment().subtract(-1, 'day')`

Comment: @sam forget the minus, was just a typo. Is there cause I tryed `moment(date).add(-1, 'day')` with the same result.

Answer (score 67):

When we get yesterday's date, there are three possibilties

**1.** Get yesterday date with current timing

```
moment().subtract(1, 'days').toString()
```

**2.** Get yesterday date with start of the day

```
moment().subtract(1, 'days').startOf('day').toString()
```

**3.** Get yesterday date with end of the day

```
moment().subtract(1, 'days').endOf('day').toString()
```

Comment: .startOf('day') is the key

Answer (score 10):

```
moment().add(-1, 'days');
```

You can find more information in the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/).

Answer (score 9):

You can easily subtract days from moment using

```
var yesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'days')
```

And for finding the previous date

```
var previousDay = moment('2017/11/6', 'YYYY/MM/DD').subtract(1, 'days')
```

Answer (score 9):

**Simplest Solution**

**By using moment we can easily get Yesterday, Today and Tomorrow Date**

**1. Get Yesterday Date:**

```
moment().subtract(1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

**2. Get Today Date:**

```
moment().subtract(0, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

**3. Get Tomorrow Date:**

```
moment().subtract(-1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Answer (score 4):

Yesterday's date in Momentjs in DD-MM-YYYY format.

```
const yesterdaydate = moment().subtract(1, "days").format("DD-MM-YYYY");
console.log(yesterdaydate)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var yesterday = new Date(dateInput.getTime());
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
console.log(yesterday);

var tomorrow = new Date(dateInput.getTime());
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
console.log(tomorrow);

dateB = moment(yesterday).format("YYYYMMDD");
dateA = moment(tomorrow).format("YYYYMMDD");
console.log(dateB);
console.log(dateA);
```