# Display Today, yesterday, tommorrow instead of dates in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, momentjs, angular2-moment

i am making an ionic app v2 in which i have to show 'today' instead of current date and 'yesterday' and 'tomorrow' also for respective dates. i tried using moment but it gives days till last week like last monday and reference time issue is also there with moment. i need for only these 3 days without reference time . can you tell me how to customize moment in ionic framework ? if you have any other suggestions than using moment . please tell. thanks in advance.
P.S: i want to implement this only in html code of ionic not in typescript code.

Comment: Can you give us any code base to work with? We do not know anything about your project. Note: It will be difficult without js/ts.

Comment: i am working on ionic framework with ts and html

Answer (score 0):

Just like this: `moment().add(-1, 'days')`. It will give you the previous day with the same exact current time that is on your local pc.

Ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448557/how-to-get-yesterdays-date-with-momentjs)

Comment: i didn't get it where should i add this moment().add() function . is it in ts file?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed that this will be difficult without JS/TS.  In your .ts file couldn't you have 3 date member variables:

```
//Set up 3 new dates, defaulting them to today
yesterday: Date = new Date();
today: Date = new Date();
tomorrow: Date = new Date();
```

And then in your ctor or init method, set them up properly (below is likely not the most valid/efficient way, but is an example).

```
//Today is already set up from instantiation, but re-set tomorrow and yesterday    
this.tomorrow.setDate(this.tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
this.yesterday.setDate(this.yesterday.getDate() - 1);
```

And then in your HTML, bind to them:

```
Yesterday was: {{yesterday?.toDateString()?.slice(0,10)}}
<br> Today is: {{today?.toDateString()?.slice(0,10)}}
<br> Tomorrow will be: {{tomorrow?.toDateString()?.slice(0,10)}}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but what it is doing ..it shows dates. i don't need that. I already have dates coming. i want to show today, yesterday instead of that day date.